# Same `queryByText()` statement for the second time fails

Tags: javascript, testing-library

Why calling the same `queryByText` for the second time gives `null` even there is no action or state changes between those calls?

```js
it('should ...', async () => {
    ...
    userEvent.upload(fileInput, file);
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText('Import')).not.toBeDisabled());
    userEvent.click(screen.queryByText('Import')); // <- fails here cause the same as above queryByText returns null
    // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'TargetElement'
    ...
});
```

If I put `screen.debug()` after `await waitFor`, it says the button is definitely there:

[image: screen.debug()]

Comment: Can you confirm it's actually the `screen.queryByText('Import')` call that's returning `null` (just log it to the console)? I suspect it's something else within the click handler in your code that's `null`. Do you perhaps need to send a custom event to the `userEvent.click` call? Adding your component code would be helpful.

Comment: thank you! logging `screen.queryByText('Import')` shows it's not `null` - my fault i didn't recognize the error was actually typescript compiler error, not runtime one

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice, the error `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'TargetElement'` actually comes from typescript compiler, it's not a runtime error.

`userEvent.click()` doesn't expect `HTMLElement | null` type which comes from `queryByText`. So the solution is just cast it like this: `screen.queryByText('Import') as HTMLElement`

Answer (score 1):

`queryBy*` is the wrong query here. It should only be used to add additional assertions for an element that *might* be there or to assert an element is *not* in the document.

The `getBy*` queries should be used to get an element that you assume to be there.
It asserts that this assumption is correct by throwing an error if no element can be found or your query is ambiguous - i.e. more than one element matches the query.